# is there any HTML5 Video plugin for chkeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, html5-video, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x, ckfinder

I need HTML5 video plugin for chkeditor5. This plugin is designed for chkeditor4. Media embed plugin that is designed for chkeditor 5 dosent meet my need. I will upload mp4 videos using chkfinder and i need chkeditor 5 to play that video. Media embed plugin can just play youtube and some other sites videos.